# Database Error PDOException Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, cakephp

I configure the website on the server getting the error, CakePHP 3 but when I point my browser to some link it gives me this errors:

> ```
> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rapidvolley'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in
> ```
>
> config/app.php.
>
> ```
> If you want to customize this error message, create src/Template/Error/pdo_error.ctp
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue, used the below DB hostname connection:

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',     
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password ', 
            'database' => 'DB name',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            'log' => false,
            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
            'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
```